# Unable retrieve a list of elements using find_elements_by_xpath in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, lxml

I am trying to make a bot which retrieves a list of links from a website using its xapth and then making it click on all the links.

The xpath looks something like this: `[@class="gridicons"]/li[i]/div/ul/li/p/a` and the `i` in the `li[i]` is from `1` to `n`, `n` being the number of links present.

The code snippet is:
`urls=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//[@id="gridicons"]/ul/li/div/ul/li/p/a')`

```
for url in urls:
    driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0]);",url.get_attribute("href"))
```

This works perfectly fine as `find_elements_by_xpath` returns a list and its being stored in `urls`. In this case, if you take a look at the xpath, each division has only one url associated with it.  [Here is an image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1qry.png)

However, if there are more than one links per division, then the xpath changes to something like this: `//*[@class="gridicons"]/li[i]/div/ul/li[j]/p/a` where `i` constitutes the number of blocks and `j` is the number of links in each block.

If I use the code:

`urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="gridicons"]/li/div/ul/li[1]/p/a')
print(urls)`

in order to retrieve only the first link on each block, when i print urls, its an empty list. I can't understand why because the inspect element box is showing me the list of urls thus making the xpath valid.
[Here is the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOGsv.png)

Comment: Add HTML sample for the same as simple text instead of images

Comment: Yes, please add the actual HTML of the section in question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are not receiving a list of elements is because you are using an absolute xpath. This means that this xpath is going to lead to exactly 1 element.

What you need to do is create a relative xpath for this element. If you add html code of the multiple `a` elements you want, I can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace absolute path to relative (note double slash before the block's 'li'):

```
urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*@class="gridicons"]//li/div/ul/li[1]/p/a')
```

This should give you every first <li> in all block <li>s

Answer (score 0):

As per your code block for single url in `WebElement` the following `xpath` works :

```
//[@id="gridicons"]/ul/li/div/ul/li/p/a
```

Now for more than one links per division you also have to cover where `WebElements` are identified by the following `xpath` :

```
//*[@class="gridicons"]/li[i]/div/ul/li[j]/p/a
```

So effectively to traverse all the `<li>` *ancestors* you can use the following code block :

```
urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[@id='gridicons']/ul//li/div/ul//li/p/a")
for url in urls:
    driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0]);",url.get_attribute("href"))
```